# How do I set primaryActionTriggered for a custom UIControl?

Tags: uikit, uicontrol, uicontrolevents, target-action

I've created a custom UIControl. The closest comparison is a UIStepper but it is a subclass of UIControl because its wholly custom.

For most UIControls you can create target actions with `primaryActionTriggered` to avoid needing to know which action matters. I want the same convenience for my custom UIControl. So how do I map `UIControl.Event.valueChanged` to `UIControl.Event.primaryActionTriggered`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you are listening for the `valueChanged` event then you just need to manually call `sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)` when that event fires

Comment: Never dawned on me it could be as simple as just sending both. Assumed there was some potentially private mapping step to make primary mean whatever the control wanted. ‍♂️